# why only the token id is successful and not the access token when using Authorizers in API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a lambda that creates the tokens for an existing user in my user pool, but when I am to validate the access token returns an error 401 and when I try with ID token it returns a 200.

```
function asyncAuthenticateUser(cognitoUser, cognitoAuthenticationDetails) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(cognitoAuthenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: resolve,
            onFailure: reject
        });
    });
}

 var authenticationData = {
                Username: name,
                Password: password,
            };
            var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
            var poolData = {
                UserPoolId: UserPoolId,
                ClientId: ClientId
            };
            var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
            var userData = {
                Username: name,
                Pool: userPool
            };
            var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
            try {
                let session = await asyncAuthenticateUser(cognitoUser, authenticationDetails);
                cognitoJWT.session = session;
                console.log(session.getIdToken());
                cognitoJWT.jwtAccess = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                cognitoJWT.jwtId = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                cognitoJWT.jwtRefresh = session.getRefreshToken().getToken();
                cognitoJWT.jwtPayloads = {
                jwtAccess: session.getAccessToken().decodePayload(),
                jwtId: session.getIdToken().decodePayload(),
                };
                callback(null, cognitoJWT);
            } catch (err){callback(err,null); }
```

My output of the Lambda is:

```
{
"StatusCode": 200,
 "StatusMessage": {
 "jwtAccess": "<<jwtAccess>>",
 "jwtRefresh":"<<jwtRefresh>>",
 "jwtId":<<jwtId>>
 }
}
```

But when I am trying to validate on the API gateway I got this output.

[Output API gateway jwtAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngr3Z.jpg)

---

If I am Try the jwtID it shows the user info.
[Output API gateway jwtId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAcZD.jpg)

Comment: API Gateway will only use idToken to Authorize . You can check the response in the question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404761/aws-api-gateway-using-access-token-with-cognito-user-pool-authorizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the wrong token to validate.
API Gateway actually uses de "idToken" for validate, not the "accessToken". So when you want to test the token, you must use the firstone.