# I got Unauthorized with access_token on API Gateway Proxy integration,works with id_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless

I saw a lot of answers on this question, but I want a valid answer,
the access token from cognito is not working but the id_token works.
That's my Authorizer:

```
ApiGatewayAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Name: ${self:custom.tablePrefix}-api-authorizer-${self:provider.stage}
      Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      RestApiId: ${file(./config/${self:provider.stage}.yml):${self:provider.region}.deploymentRestApiId}
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      ProviderARNs:
        - !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn
```

[image: Authorizer]

[image: OAuth]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [define a Resource Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html#cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers-console) in your Cognito User Pool and add [AuthorizationScopes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-authorizationscopes) to your `AWS::API::Method`s. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404761/aws-api-gateway-using-access-token-with-cognito-user-pool-authorizer)  and this [Knowledge Base article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-custom-scopes-api-gateway/) for more details.