# How do I create an API Gateway that uses both client credentials and user auth flows with Cognito using AWS CDK v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I need both types of OAuth flows for my API because I have users signing up via the web as well as applications talking directly to the API, e.g. Grafana, user integrations, etc.

I've set up both flows in my infra but only user logins work. Client credentials will not authorize against APIGW endpoints.

Here's my Cognito `AuthStack`:

```js
export class AuthStack extends Stack {
    public userPool!: UserPool;
    private userPoolClient!: UserPoolClient;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        this.userPool = new UserPool(this, "MyUserPool", {
            selfSignUpEnabled: true,
            signInAliases: {
                username: true,
                email: true
            }
        });

        this.userPool.addDomain("MyUserPoolDomain", {
            cognitoDomain: {
                domainPrefix: "my-auth-prototype"
            }
        });

        new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "MyAdminPoolGroup", {
            userPoolId: this.userPool.userPoolId,
            groupName: "admin"
        });

        const clientReadServerScope = new ResourceServerScope({
            scopeName: "client.read",
            scopeDescription: "client read scope",
        });

        const resourceServer = new UserPoolResourceServer(this, "ClientCredentialsResourceServer", {
            identifier: "client-credentials-resource-server",
            userPool: this.userPool,
            scopes: [clientReadServerScope],
        });

        this.userPoolClient = this.userPool.addClient("MyUserPoolClient", {
            accessTokenValidity: Duration.minutes(60),
            generateSecret: true,
            refreshTokenValidity: Duration.days(1),
            enableTokenRevocation: true,
            oAuth: {
                flows: {
                    clientCredentials: true,
                },
                scopes: [OAuthScope.resourceServer(resourceServer, clientReadServerScope)],
            },
            authFlows: {
                adminUserPassword: true,
                custom: true,
                userPassword: true,
                userSrp: true
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

`ApiStack`

```js
export class ApiStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ApiStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const api = new RestApi(this, "MyApi", {
            binaryMediaTypes: ["*/*"]
        });

        //Cognito authorizor
        const authorizer = new CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, "MyApiAuthorizor", {
            cognitoUserPools: [props.userPool],
            identitySource: "method.request.header.Authorization"
        });
        authorizer._attachToApi(api);

        //Cognito options
        const optionsWithAuth: MethodOptions = {
            authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
            authorizer: {
                authorizerId: authorizer.authorizerId
            }
        };

        //CORS options
        const optionsWithCors: ResourceOptions = {
            defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
                allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
                allowMethods: Cors.ALL_METHODS
            }
        };

        //base resource
        const dataPipelineResource = api.root.addResource("my-resource", optionsWithCors);

        dataPipelineResource.addMethod("GET", props.lambdaIntegration, optionsWithAuth);
    }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve a valid `access_token` like so:

```js
export const getClientToken = async (clientId: string, clientSecret: string): Promise<string | null> => {
    const authEndpoint = "https://my-auth-prototype.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token";
    const res = await fetch(authEndpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString("base64")
        }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return data.access_token;
};
```

But if I use it against the `my-resource` GET endpoint in API Gateway defined above, I get a `401 Unauthorized` response.

How do I connect the two? Does it have something to do with the `ResourceServerScope` that I've defined? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by picking apart [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73656620/1167996). I changed the relevant parts of the AuthStack like so:

```js
const myServerScope = new ResourceServerScope({
    scopeName: "my-resource",
    scopeDescription: "my-resource scope",
});

const resourceServer = new UserPoolResourceServer(this, "ClientCredentialsResourceServer", {
    identifier: "prod",
    userPool: this.userPool,
    scopes: [myServerScope],
});

this.userPoolClient = this.userPool.addClient("MyUserPoolClient", {
    generateSecret: true,
    enableTokenRevocation: true,
    accessTokenValidity: Duration.minutes(60),
    refreshTokenValidity: Duration.days(1),
    oAuth: {
        flows: {
            clientCredentials: true
        },
        scopes: [
            OAuthScope.resourceServer(resourceServer, myServerScope)
        ],
    },
    authFlows: {
        adminUserPassword: true,
        userPassword: true,
        userSrp: true,
        custom: true
    }
});
```

Then, matched it to the `authorizationScopes` prop in the method options, in the `ApiStack`:

```js
const optionsWithAuth: MethodOptions = {
    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
    authorizer: {
        authorizerId: authorizer.authorizerId
    },
    authorizationScopes: [
        "prod/my-resource"
    ]
};
```

Both user and client credentials can use the AccessKey to auth against the API, and all works wonderfully.